# Regular expression in python is skipping first 2 characters of line

Tags: python, regex, expression

I have a text file that looks like this

```
Name     #Variants  #Cases  #Controls

CNGA3   5   5   0
GPR125  4   3   0
IGHMBP2 4   4   0
STK11IP 4   4   0
ACAD9   3   3   0
ANKRD17 3   3   0
```

I want to parse through this file and return all of the gene names (the `name` column) to a list - `list_of_genes`, or something like that.

I have the following code

```
gene_list = []
for i in range (6, 7):
    run_file = open('run_{}_results.txt'.format(i))
    gene = re.compile('[^\s]*', re.I)
    for line in run_file:
        match=gene.match(line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if match:
            matched_gene = match.group()
            gene_list.append(matched_gene)
```

When I run that code, the result I get is

```
['GA3', 'R125', 'HMBP2', 'K11IP', 'AD9', 'KRD17']
```

The regex is skipping the first two characters of every gene and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your coding style is nobody else's  business, but you'll get better responses if you go to the trouble of isolating the problem code for us and composing a simpler question-- all those `i` and `j` loops are irrelevant here.

Comment: As an aside, in Python, you almost never use or need index variables to iterate over something. Instead, you iterate directly over the list, dictionary or whatever collection datatype you have. No need for `i`, `j` etc.

Comment: @alexis will do, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TimPietzcker that was because I didn't want it to look at the first line in the file, and i didn't know any other way to skip it.

Comment: Just do `next(runfile)` or `runfile.readline()` to skip a line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
match=gene.match(line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

The [second parameter to a regex object's `match()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) is `pos`, meaning the starting position for the match operation. `re.IGNORECASE` happens to be `2`.

You have already defined the regex to be case-insensitive when compiling it, so of course there is no need to do that again (and thus no way to do it). Furthermore, your regex doesn't need that option anyway because it doesn't contain any cased characters.

While I'm at it, `"[^\s]*"` should be `r"\S*"`.

Comment: @Petera, since that solved your problem you should now "accept" the answer by clicking on the big check mark next to it.

Comment: @alexis gotcha. meant to do that but slipped my mind.thanks again!